# Wordpress SQL with category addition

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have some SQL in a plugin that selects Wordpress users based on what posts they have made. The issue I have is also requiring that posts are from a certain category. I have looked at the terms table but I am not getting any further.

Here is the SQL code I have to far.

```
SELECT u.ID, u.user_nicename, u.display_name, u.user_email, p.post_date 
FROM $wpdb->users u 
INNER JOIN (SELECT post_author, MAX(post_date) post_date 
            FROM $wpdb->posts 
            WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_title != 'Auto Draft' AND post_title != '' AND post_status = 'publish' 
            GROUP BY post_author) p 
WHERE u.ID = p.post_author 
ORDER BY u.display_name
```

I think I want to add something like the below to the query but I'm not sure.

```
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
```

Comment: You're going to have to do two more joins to link the posts table to the term taxonomy and term relationships table. Then you could have your WHERE clause for the category. This might be easier using the built in wordpress functions though.

Comment: Is this based upon something you saw somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.ID, u.user_nicename, u.display_name, u.user_email, p.post_date, p.ID, ktt.taxonomy, kct.Name
FROM kc_users u 
INNER JOIN (SELECT post_author, MAX(post_date) post_date, ID
        FROM kc_posts 
        WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_title != 'Auto Draft' AND post_title != '' AND post_status = 'publish' 
        GROUP BY post_author) p 
INNER JOIN kc_term_relationships ktr ON ktr.object_id = p.ID
INNER JOIN kc_term_taxonomy ktt ON ktt.term_id = ktr.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN kc_terms kct ON kct.term_id = ktt.term_id
WHERE u.ID = p.post_author 
AND ktt.taxonomy = 'category'
-- AND kct.Name = 'your description filter' <- Filter here
ORDER BY u.display_name
```

Obviously your prefix for your table names will be different than mine